# Bulk remove provisioning profiles on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration-profiles

Over time I've accumulated many (valid) provisioning profiles on my device, and now have  over 400 in Settings. The only way I know of removing them is going into each one individually.

Is there an easy way to remove many of them at a time?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that using the Organizer in Xcode allows you to do this.

Comment: It is ultra slow. Not only you can't select more than one provisioning profile at a time, it takes several seconds to delete the currently selected one and become responsive again after you hit "delete". I mistakenly set the "Team" in my target and now I have all 100+ provisioning profiles installed. All apps take forever to launch. The only easy way out is to restore to factory settings.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can’t batch delete them in Xcode 6 anymore. You can use [Mac Auto Mouse Click](http://www.murgaa.com/mac-auto-mouse-click/) to setup two steps that click on the minus sign then click on the last provisioning profile by defining X and Y coordinates. Set a high repeat count and all your provisioning profiles will disappear automatically.

Here is another option (that I haven’t tested) suggested by [Filippo Bigarella](http://twitter.com/FilippoBiga/status/562614397689143297) using [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org):

> for uuid in `ideviceprovision list | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1}'`; do ideviceprovision remove $uuid; done

You can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install libimobiledevice if you don't want to build it from source.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) can be used to remove a batch of provisioning profiles.

Comment: Sir, you win the internets for this weekend. It took about 45 minutes to remove 400+ profiles but at least it is automated. Seems to delete at a rate of one a second. It was taking me 10-15 seconds for any non Apple app to load previously, now they are all loading instant.